# Is it vulnerable to set passwords in request.setAttribute(key,value)

Tags: java, jsp, security

Initially i set my passwords in request.setAttribute, but now i got a doubt like it is possible to hack my password from this.

Comment: Please add some detail about the nature of threat you're asking about and ideally some sample code of what you're trying to do.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), and update your question then. In short: do not write an essay explaining what you (want to) do, **show your code** instead (what have you tried so far).